# Why does this short circuit evaluation return undefined if first value is false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean-operations, short-circuit-evaluation

I have an example similar to this where the first expression evaluates to false and the second is undefined but the overall expression returns undefined into valueResult, shouldn't the first false value terminate the check and return false?

```
valueResult = false && 10 === 5 ? 'match' : undefined
```

I have added console log statements and a debugger and this is what is happening, however when I do false && undefined on the browser console, it returns false.

Comment: honestly, how are we supposed to support you there? You are right - short circuit should definitely return false. Please provide your real data or anything

Comment: I've updated the code to match more closely to what I'm seeing. The actual code was on another machine so I'm giving an identical example

Comment: Your code basically works like `(false && 10 === 5) ? 'match' : undefined`

Comment: Thanks I've got it now, how do you know that implicit grouping is made with parentheses?

Comment: because of precedence... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your updated example, the logical AND `… && …` has a higher order of precedence (5) than the evaluation of the ternary `… ? … : …` (3).

Check out the table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table

Comment: The ternary contains a === check which is higher priority than the && though. Either way, in theory the first value of false should be returned right? are there any scenarios where it wouldn't and undefined would come back?

Comment: yes, === has a higher precedence, but &&-operator is still higher than the ternary operator, that's the whole point! What you want is this: ```false && (10 === 5 ? 'match' : undefined)```. But what you get is this: ```(false && 10 === 5) ? 'match' : undefined```. Again: it has nothing to do with the === operator

Comment: Thanks, thats better, you have the right number of parentheses there so it makes more sense now.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the source of confusion here, @j-obe. The ternary operator has right-to-left associativity -- check out the 'conditional chains' example for it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#examples) to see why it returns `undefined` in your example; the `&&` is basically short-circuited.

Answer (score 1):

&&-operator has higher precedence then the ternary operator. That's why following is happening:

Basically you have a ternary operator `(false && (10 === 5) ? : 'match' : undefined`. `10 === 5` evaluates to false and `false && false` also results in false. Thats why undefined and not 'match' is returned.

To fix this, add parentheses after && like this:

```
 false && (10 === 5 ? 'match' : undefined)
```

Comment: Not sure if the question has been misread, I don't want 'match' returned, I'm wondering why undefined is returned when the first value before the && is false

Comment: No it's not missread. I just broke down the evaluation. Just add parentheses and it's fixed

Comment: Ok, maybe I have missed the bit with the answer, I'm not sure why undefined is being returned in my example based on what you've explained

Comment: Because of precedence. && Has higher precedence than ternary operator

Comment: I understand based on a comment someone else has made now, I think you're missing a parentheses in your answer which confused me with your explanation.

Comment: no I wrote in my first sentence "precedence is important. add parentheses" and corrected your expression, so it should work like you expect it to do. what is so missunderstanding to you? Edited my answer

Comment: If your whole point is about adding parentheses then you must ensure you use the correct number of parentheses in your answer, you are missing one, so it's confusing.

Comment: Dude, just add parentheses: false && (10 === 5 ? 'match' : undefined). Problem fixed. What's left?